# Rails 6 application.js not reflecting changes, webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I was trying to install jquery for Ruby on Rails 6, which doesn't work. Upon inspection I see that *application.js* is not being updated.

[image: inspection on chrome]

*application.html.erb*

```
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %
```

*application.js*

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import "boostrap"
```

*environment.js*

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Gemfile `gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'`

Jquery was installed running `yarn add jquery`

I've already tried some solutions on the niternet, like deleting the public folder, and running `bundle exec rake assets:clean`

Comment: Sanity check: Are you using the webpack-dev-server? If so, restart after adding packages with ‘yarn add.’

Comment: No I'm not. Is it necessary? I just wanted to use the default webpacker that comes with rails 6